# creating multiple objects automatically numbered

Tags: c++

I've got a basic question. 
Is it possible to number objects automatically?
So for example if I have a class 'item' and in the main I have

```
item item1(weight, length);
item item2(weight, length);
```

and in the constructor of the item class we assign the weight and length to the corresponding variables.

```
class item {

public:
item(int w, int l){
weight = w ;
length = l ;
itemnumber = ??? ;

private:
int weight;
int length;
int itemnumber;
};
```

But on top of that I also want a variable itemnumber. This itemnumber should be 1 the first time I create an object  (so 1 for item1) and 2 the second object created (item2) and so on. But I don't want to pass it as a parameter. So basically what should I put instead of the '???' in my code ?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Create a static field inside class, and increment it in constructor.

something like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : itemnumber(nextNum) { ++nextNum; }
private:
    int itemnumber;
    static int nextNum;
}

// in CPP file initialize it
int A::nextNum = 1;
```

Also, don't forget to increment static field in copy and move constructors\operators.

Comment: Don't forget to increment it in the copy/move constructor too!

Comment: @Rakete1111 Hope it's not too late but what exactly do you mean by increment it in copy/move constructor?

Comment: @PieterDe Nope, not too late :) When you copy an object, the copy constructor is called, which copies the object, i.e. `A a; A b = a;` Now if you don't increment `nextNum` in the copy constructor, then both `a` and `b` will have the same `itemnumber`, which isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

with a static variable like

```
class rect{
public:
static int num;
rect(){num++;}
};

int rect::num =0;
int main(){
rect a();
cout << rect::num;
}
```